# Using new values of random intercepts to predict values in lme4 R package

Tags: r, predict, lme4, random-effects

Let's say we have a following prediction:

```
mod <- y ~ x + (1+x | Subject)
```

Is there a way to predict new values in y, using the predict() function not by specifying only new fixed effects by using newdata arguement, but also by specifying a single random intercept value for which the predictions should be calculated?

According to my logic it should look something like this:

```
predict(mod, newdata = data.frame(x = seq(1,10, length.out=100), Subject$'(Intercept)' = 2)
```

Comment: Your request does not make sense to me. However, you can easily do a population-level prediction and add your "fixed random intercept" value to the predicted value.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know the slope for the new predict function if I only specify the fixed intercept. This is basically what I want to know - how to I get the value of the slope for the specifically set random intercept which was not observed.

Comment: You can't predict for a subject that was not observed. You can only predict for subjects that were observed or for the population.

Comment: Ok, but then I suppose I can use the simulate() function, right? How would that work in my case?